# Facebook login in your app without facebook login button

Tags: android

I am trying to built a facebook login in my app without using the facebook login button. Instead I want to use my own button. What is the procedure to achieve this ? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by facebook login button ?

Comment: See [this](http://www.rahuljiresal.com/2014/03/facebook-login-for-android-without-loginbutton/)

Comment: means facebook widget button... i want my button and on clicking my button it should ask for facebook login

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do facebook login without using facebook loginbutton.
First, use ProfileTracker and CallbackManager along with LoginManager read/write permissions.

After, successful authentication callbackmanager gets a callback and use ProfileTracker callback to get info about the user.

Check facebook tutorials for more detailed info.

Comment: can u tell in detail in a flow.. so that i can write my code in same flow... and do u have code for the same .. it will be helpful..

Comment: I have already shared the flow with you. Please check facebook samples for more detailed flow and code. I do have the code, but I am unable to share with you now.